# How to combine multiple lists using LINQ lambda

Tags: c#, linq

I have two lists:

```
list1 = [a,b,c,4]
list2 = [1,23,5,6]
```

Now I need to create an anonymous object using linq lambda.

Something like.

```
list1 = DataTable.AsEnumerable().toList();
list2 = DataTable.AsEnumerable().toList();

var result = list1.Where(x => x.Field<int>(1) == 2018).Select(x => new[] {
new {x = "XYZ", y = x[0], z = list2[0]},
....}



}
```

How do I go about doing this?

Comment: Can you provide a real sample input, and the output you expect to get from it?

Comment: Honestly it's just a simple list of numbers and strings (mixed). I don't have access to it atm but I can provide it tomorrow.

Comment: Please add code that the compiler will accept. Please show sample output from sample input.

Comment: ^ I don't know how to approach the problem. I have given what I have so far.

Comment: @CaesarTex - Your question needs to contain real C# code - not the made up `list1 = [a,b,c,4]`.

Answer (score 0):

You need [`Zip`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) Linq method, consider this example:

```
int[] list1 = {1, 2, 3};
string[] list2 = {"a", "b", "c"};

var result = list1.Zip(list2, (i, s) => new {y = i, z = i});
```

Comment: I'm getting the type arguments for 'Enumerable.Zip'...cannot be inferred from the usage. The lists are var type and contain multiple types. I'm using datatable.AsEnumerable..then to List() to create these lists.

Comment: In this case, could you update the question with a proper simplified example?

Comment: I've added some info about list

Comment: @CaesarTex - There is no `var` type - it's just syntactic sugar for a real type.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine, it just needs some small fixes:

```
            string [] list1 = { "a", "b", "c", "4" };
            int[] list2 = { 1, 23, 5, 6 };
            object[] list3 = { "test", DateTime.Now, 56 };

            var result = list1.Where(x => x == "a").Select(x =>
                  new { x = "XYZ", y = x[0], z = list2[0], t = list3[1] }).ToList();
```